# Extended (JWT) OncePerRequestFilter cannot be invoked. because @Autowire is failing sothat this.Class is returning null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm currently building a standard `JwtAuthorizationFilter`. I extend the `OncePerRequestFilter class` for this. Furthermore I have a `JwtUtils class`, which contains all JWT methods. For example, one method validates the JWT bearer token. However, I keep getting the error that this method (and all others) cannot be invoked because `this.jwtUtils` is null.

So bassicly I am trying to `autowire` the JwtUtils classe. But `Spring` is not giving any `instance`. Instead it is giving `null`

Thats my error message

```
Cannot invoke ... jwt.JwtUtils.validateJwtToken(String)" because "this.jwtUtils" is null
```

JwtAuthorizationFilter class (the error is throwing here)

```
@Slf4j
public class JwtAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

  @Autowired private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
  @Autowired private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(
          HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      String jwt = JwtUtils.resolveToken(request);
      System.out.println("before if " + jwt);
      if (jwtUtils.validateJwtToken(jwt)) { // ERROR !
        String username = jwtUtils.getUserNameFromJwtToken(jwt);
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
      }

    } catch (Exception e) {
      JwtAuthorizationFilter.log.error("Cannot set user authentication: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
  }
}
```

JwtUtils class

```
import io.jsonwebtoken.ExpiredJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.MalformedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.UnsupportedJwtException;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.SignatureException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Date;

@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtUtils {

  @Value("${ggg.app.jwtSecret}")
  private String jwtSecret;

  @Value("${ggg.app.jwtExpirationMs}")
  private long jwtExpirationMs;

  @Value("${ggg.app.jwtRefreshExpirationMs}")
  private long jwtRefreshExpirationMs;

  static String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
    String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
    if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) return bearerToken.substring(7);
    return null;
  }

  public String generateJwtAccessToken(String username) {
    return generateTokenFromUsername(username, jwtExpirationMs);
  }

  public String generateJwtRefreshToken(String username) {
    return generateTokenFromUsername(username, jwtRefreshExpirationMs);
  }

  private String generateTokenFromUsername(String username, Long expiration) {
    return Jwts.builder()
        .setSubject(username)
        .setIssuedAt(new Date())
        .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + expiration))
        .signWith(secretKey())
        .compact();
  }

  public String getUserNameFromJwtToken(String token) {
    return Jwts.parserBuilder()
        .setSigningKey(secretKey())
        .build()
        .parseClaimsJws(token)
        .getBody()
        .getSubject();
  }

  public boolean validateJwtToken(String token) {
    try {
      Jwts.parserBuilder().setSigningKey(secretKey()).build().parseClaimsJws(token);
      return true;
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
      JwtUtils.log.error("Invalid JWT signature: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
      JwtUtils.log.error("Invalid JWT token: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
      JwtUtils.log.error("JWT token is expired: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
      JwtUtils.log.error("JWT token is unsupported: {}", e.getMessage());
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
      JwtUtils.log.error("JWT claims string is empty: {}", e.getMessage());
    }
    return false;
  }

  private SecretKey secretKey() {
    return Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(jwtSecret.getBytes());
  }
}
```

WebSecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Autowired private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

  @Bean
  private static PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
  }

  @Bean
  private static JwtAuthorizationFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthorizationFilter();
  }

  //  @Override
  //  public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder)
  //      throws Exception {
  //    authenticationManagerBuilder
  //        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
  //        .passwordEncoder(WebSecurityConfig.passwordEncoder());
  //  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    // Disable CSRF (cross site request forgery)
    http.cors()
        .and()
        .csrf()
        .disable()
        // No session will be created or used by spring security
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**", "/confirm-account")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest()
        .authenticated();

    // Apply JWT
    http.addFilterBefore(
        WebSecurityConfig.authenticationJwtTokenFilter(),
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

Problem solver ?

```
 @Bean
  public JwtAuthorizationFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthorizationFilter();
  }
```

I found out that the private static JwtAuthorizationFilter
authenticationJwtTokenFilter() method is calling the issue. If i change that to a public method it is working, although passwordEncoder is privat static and is used in my auth service . Unfortunately it is my plugin which is causing that problem. It changes the code automatically. Does somebody know what to do ?

AuthService class

```
@Service
public class AuthService implements AuthServiceRepository {

  @Autowired private RoleRepository roleRepository;
  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;
  @Autowired private PasswordEncoder encoder;
  @Autowired private JwtUtils jwtUtils;
  @Autowired private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
  @Autowired private UserService userService;
  @Autowired private EmailService emailService;
  @Autowired private ConfirmationTokenRepository confirmationTokenRepository;

@Override
  public JwtResponse signUpUser(SignUpRequest signUpRequest, String siteURL)
      throws MessagingException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    String accessToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtAccessToken(signUpRequest.getUsername());
    String refreshToken = jwtUtils.generateJwtRefreshToken(signUpRequest.getUsername());
    Set<Role> roles = SignUpRequest.getRoles(signUpRequest, roleRepository);
    AppUser user =
        new AppUser(
            signUpRequest.getUsername(),
            signUpRequest.getEmail(),
                encoder.encode(signUpRequest.getPassword()));
    user.setRoles(roles);

    user.setEnabled(false);
    AppUser newUser = userService.saveUser(user);
    ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = new ConfirmationToken(user);
    confirmationTokenRepository.save(confirmationToken);
    emailService.sendVerificationEmail(user, siteURL, confirmationToken.getConfirmationToken());
    List<String> userRoles =
        newUser.getRoles().stream().map(role -> role.getName().name()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new JwtResponse(
        accessToken,
        refreshToken,
        user.getId(),
        signUpRequest.getUsername(),
        signUpRequest.getEmail(),
        userRoles);
  } ... }
```

Comment: Remove `static` from the bean method and just reference/call the method and instead of `UserDetailsServiceImpl` inject `UserDetailsService` (use the interface not the implementation).

Comment: @M.Deinum both things things should certainly be improved, but have nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: This is my IDEA (Intellij IDEAD auto /  save Actions) which is changing the code in that way I really do not want to deactovate that feature. But removing the privat static is solving that problem indeed

Comment: Either remove that clearly counterproductive plugin or get used to living with that problem. Your problem is solved.

Comment: @AngrySnyder save actions are important. I really would like to keep them. I think the logic is maybe wrong and I should try a different approach. By the way why is static even causing that problem ?. I am using private static PasswordEncoder as well ?

Comment: Because you are only using JwtAuthorizationFilter outside the WebSecurityConfig class and not PasswordEncoder. If you would inject PasswordEncoder somewhere else you would have the same problem. If the bean method is private there is no way for other classes to see that bean.

Comment: Just use it like this (without private static, add public if needed):
@Bean
  JwtAuthorizationFilter authenticationJwtTokenFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthorizationFilter();
  }

Same for PasswordEncoder.

Comment: I am using the PasswordEncoder in my authentication Service. Thats what is confusing me.

Comment: Can you show the authentication service?

Comment: Sure ! one second please

Comment: You can see it now :D. thy for the help btw

Comment: Is PasswordEncoder annotated with @Component/@Service or not?

Comment: PasswordEncoder is just declared the the @Bean annotation in the WebSecurityConfig class

Comment: I honestly think the way I am adding that filter is just bad practise. there must be another better way

Comment: @maxfromgermany See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71312077/15835039).

Comment: Spring security has built in jwt filter support since 2018. There is no need at all to implement custom filter. https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture Shows how to do at, as well as Steves link. There is A LOT of faulty blogs out there claiming that you need to build something custom, which is just flat out wrong and bad practice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's because JwtUtils and WebSecurityConfig are not registered as Spring Beans. Try to add a @Component annotation to the classes.

More about dependency injection in Spring Boot: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.spring-beans-and-dependency-injection

Comment: Hi I did that it is still not working :(

Comment: I added a @Component annotation to the  JwtUtils class.( I also edited my in my question). It is still not working. I am really frustrated because I do not see my mistake here

Comment: Make sure to add it, without that annotation the JwtUtils class is not in Spring Boot's application context. Have you added the @SpringBootApplication annotation to your "main" class which starts your application?

Comment: Yes I did that!

Comment: I did both. Wait i will post my whole JwtUtils

Comment: I posted my whole JwtUtils class. could you take a look please ?

Comment: If JwtUtils is annotated with @Component, then it is a problem with the component scan. Where is your main class (did you place it in a specific package or at the root (src/main/java) folder)? When you use the annotation SpringBootApplication, i think that the default behaviour is that all packages that are at the same level or under your app main class will be scan (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: Ah, you also need to make JwtAuthorizationFilter a Spring bean. Autowired members must be defined in a valid Spring bean (@Component|@Service|...).

Comment: JwtUtils is under the main class. The main class is at the root! I have not moved the main class since I started my project. the JwtUtils is in a jwt package which is in the security package

Comment: @AngrySnyder I tried that as well it is not working. I am really confused

Comment: I created those 3 classes quickly locally (without all the fuss) and the dependency injection worked for me. If you add the annotations as I said it should work. Try to comment out code in your classes until it works.

Comment: hmm I believe you. But something stupid must be causing that problem. I cannot start the application without that fuss. There must be a stupid reason

Comment: @AngrySnyder do you think some method in jwtUtils is causing that problem ?

Comment: @AngrySnyder I found out that the private static JwtAuthorizationFilter 
authenticationJwtTokenFilter() method is calling the issue. If i change that to a public method it is working. Unfortunately it is my plugin which is causing that problem. It changes the code automatically. Do you know what to do ?

Comment: @maxfromgermany I have no idea what plugin you mean :) Disable/remove it. By the way the "static" is also not optimal and should be removed.

Comment: IntelliJ save Actions

Comment: @AngrySnyder save actions are important. I really would like to keep them

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense (hence the downvote). The `WebSecurityConfig` is an `@Configuration` and thus it is a component and detected. The problem is due to the `static` bean method the filter isn't registered as a spring bean, removing the static will make the filter a spring bean due to a proper `@Bean` method.

Comment: Hi @maxfromgermany, Did you solve this issue, am stucked on this issue?