# Implementing Authorization in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have a use case in which I have to perform authorization part only. JWT token is getting generated by another service. My service will only consume that token which will have data in it's custom claim. In my spring boot application, I just want to verify that token if it's valid or not before allowing users to access any API. In all answers I can see one Authentication object is created from current Security context. Is there any way in spring in which I don't need to write so much unnecessary code in Custom Filter and just write the logic to parse JWT token and if it is valid, then allow user to API or else send unauthorized response?

Auth0 Java JWT provides few methods to verify JWT token. I want to validate and parse using code like below

```
Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secret);
JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).withIssuer(issuer).build();
DecodedJWT decoded = verifier.verify(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work with spring security you have to work with those things (filters, authentication object, context, etc.). You have to set an Authentication to be able to access protected resources. It's not complicated at all, you don't have to write "useless" code but just tell spring security what you want to do.

In your case, you just have to provide a custom filter that matches your criterias.

We can imagine something like :

```
@Component
public class TokenAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    
    
  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    // Here, I get the token from authorization header, change if you get it from anywhere else
    String token = httpRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
    
    // here i'm just doing a dummy check. if my token equals "mysupersecrettoken" the authentication is validated
    // change this test by yours (using Auth0 etc.)
    if ("mysupersecrettoken".equals(token)) {
      // dummy authentication object. You can set a real username / credentials / role based on the claims of your token if you want to.
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken user = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("username", "credentials",
          Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE")));
      SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(user);
    }
    // call next filters, if authentication is not valid, no authentication will be set so user will not be authenticated
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

}
```

It's not the best way to work with spring security but it's a kind of "minimal" way to achieve your usecase. You'll probably need to set some security context too but it's not a big thing.

Comment: This answer is straight up faulty, spring security has a built in configurable JWT filter since 2018. Why build something that already exists in spring security. Also building custom security is bad practice. Downvoted

Comment: Please read up on how JWTs work in spring security before answering any questions https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html#oauth2resourceserver-jwt-architecture

Comment: @Toerktumlare The built in configurable JWT works on a OAuth2 basis. the token must respect a certain form for the default filters to work properly. As the OP didn't precise anything on the nature of the token he receives from his authorization server, you can't assume that it will work with the default implementation of spring security resource server. I know that this is not the best way to work with spring security, I've precised it. Do not be condescending and take all parameters into account before answering. In addition, you say something about it in your SO profile

Comment: That is the exact reason as to why there are security standards. To prevent people from building custom security solutions. Buildig custom security is bad practice. And thats how it is, weather you like it or not.

Comment: @Toerktumlare I agree with you on this point but did you work for a company as a developer? Implementing out of the box solution is the best way to go, ok. But you have to work with a context. You can't always implement what you want following best practices. There's always constraints (technology, integration, environment,..). In this case, I provided a solution that will 100% work with the context provided by the OP. We don't know if the authorization server works with OAuth2 and if he has a hand on it. I responded to the pratical case, you're stuck on theory.

Comment: here at stack overflow we answer questions based on what information is given. If information is missing, then you either ask for it or you dont answer. Whatever the context is, implementing custom security is bad practice. And thats that. Spring security has a built in JWT filter that is battle tested in thousands of production applications, it follows RFC6729 and is customizable for most needs. There is nothing more to say on the subject. This answer is faulty.

Comment: I was waiting for that kind of response. It confirms that you have never implemented complex authentication systems based on this framework. I had done a lot of work with Spring security, in e-banking and insurance companies. Their authentication systems are so specific that you have no alternative but to break the framework and customize some stuff. Some OAuth2 specifications are not considered as 100% secure in these sectors (e.g. refresh token system). I did not ask for more details, you're right, it's my mistake but yours is to be a closed-minded developer.

Comment: @Toerktumlare And you didn't answered to the secret sharing thing, is it described in [RFC6729](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc6729) as a good practice? If you're battling against all the bad security practices on SO, follow your rules all the way!

Comment: I have no idea what you are referring to, also, what i have done or not done has nothing to do with the question, you have no idea of my experience and im going to keep it that way. if you have a problem with others answers then you take it up with them. Have a nice day

Comment: @Toerktumlare Of course you have no idea, you don't know what you're talking about. No good sir, I have no problem with other people's answers, I have a problem with random "experts" giving advices on subjects they know nothing about. Have a nice day too!

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security ships with out of the box support for JWT authentication, so you would not need to write any code aside from configuration. See [OAuth 2.0 Resource Server JWT](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) in the reference docs. You can enable it with the Spring Security DSL using:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(OAuth2ResourceServerConfigurer::jwt)
```

Note that JWTs can be used outside of OAuth 2.0 with this support, though it may not be obvious at first that this is the case. You can check out the [JWT Login sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) to see how that is accomplished, but the main takeaway is that you need to provide an `@Bean` of type `JwtDecoder` that is created with a public key, such as:

```java
@Bean
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    return NimbusJwtDecoder.withPublicKey(this.key).build();
}
```

Also see this [Tanzu Tuesday talk](https://tanzu.tv/tt/61) for a deep dive on this subject.

Comment: I am not using public and private key. Instead I am using signing key, secret and issuer which are of type string. NimbusJwtDecoder has method to take secret but of type SecretKey not of string. Also there is no authorization server where the logic to verify and decode the token is exposed as api. The service which is generating token is written in Golang.

Comment: Using a public key is just an example of one way. Anything you can do by implementing or providing a `JwtDecoder` will satisfy this requirement. I'm not deeply familiar with Nimbus capabilities, but you can use `NimbusJwtDecoder.SecretKeyJwtDecoderBuilder` to customize those options. Or you can simply provide your own decoder implementation using another library. That would be the ideal way to hook into this support for JWTs.